# Can we use SOAP protocol with Transport Layer protocol?

Tags: .net, wcf, asp.net-web-api

Generally SOAP protocol transmitted over HTTP protocol and it also support other Application layer protocol (SMTP & Othes). Can we use Transport layer protocol (TCP,UDP)  for SOAP and does REST work only HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

The widely used protocol is HTTP, but there are some implementations available for SOAP over UDP or Soap over tcp.

For example:
[Soap-Over-UDP](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/soapoverudp/1.1/os/wsdd-soapoverudp-1.1-spec-os.html)

Also if both parties are using WCF, it supports netTCPBidning out of the box, for TCP transport.